# Select distinct rows with max date in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose having query

```
SELECT c_id, id, max(date) as max_date FROM table
GROUP BY c_id,updated
```

And following result:

```
c_id, id, max_date
1     5   2017-12-28 16:09:20 
1     6   2019-12-28 16:09:20
2     7   2017-12-28 16:09:20
2     8   2019-12-28 16:09:20
```

I expect to get:

```
c_id, id, max_date 
1     6   2019-12-28 16:09:20
2     8   2019-12-28 16:09:20
```

How to achieve that in mysql 5.7?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `updated`? That means you want different rows for each value of that column.

Comment: Without grouping by updated, it will place the wrong id in the resultset
 
1     5   2019-12-28 16:09:20
2     7   2019-12-28 16:09:20

Comment: It's getting the wrong id because this isn't the right way to get the ID with the max date. It has nothing to do with updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.c_id = t.c_id);
```

Comment: There is a mistake in your query near "from t t2", maybe you mean "from table t2".

And it produces the wrong number of rows. I receive 2 rows for one c_id  and wrong dates also

Comment: @Ahmed . . . `table` isn't a reasonable table name so I made up a placeholder, `t`.

Comment: not sure it works in mysql

Comment: @Ahmed It should work. See the linked question for lots of other ways to do it. Replace `t` with the actual name of your table.

Comment: sorry. I didn't read your query properly. I thought there is table in the first place. By the way, it is t. Your query is correct, but do not solve my problem.